# How to select only those rows which are greater than modified time using spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For Example ,

I have created a table ,

```
CREATE DATABASE es_db;
USE es_db;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS es_table;
CREATE TABLE es_table (
  id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY unique_id (id),
  client_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  modification_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  insertion_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Now assume i have to select those data which are greater than time i give as input .

consider this query for example,

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modification_time) AS unix_ts_in_secs FROM es_table WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(modification_time) > :sql_last_modifiedvalue AND modification_time < NOW()) ORDER BY modification_time ASC
```

Is there away to translate the same to native query ? i can achieve the same with jdbctemplate but would like to know if this is possible with native query?

Comment: And how is this related to spring data?

Comment: How is this not a native query?